# Why this question was closed?

Tags: discussion, support

This question was closed as subjective and argumentative:
[What's your favourite “super user” Anti-boss technique](https://superuser.com/questions/182282/whats-your-favourite-super-user-anti-boss-technique)

Waiting for the "[Not Programming related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related)" proposal, i thought my question would fit here on SuperUser.
Here some other examples of questions not closed that sound like mine:

[What's Your Favorite Harmless Computer Practical Joke?](https://superuser.com/questions/4714/whats-your-favorite-harmless-computer-practical-joke)
[What's your favourite “super user” cartoon?](https://superuser.com/questions/554/whats-your-favourite-super-user-cartoon)
[What's the weirdest thing you've ever seen a non-techie do to a computing device?](https://superuser.com/questions/5321/whats-the-weirdest-thing-youve-ever-seen-a-non-techie-do-to-a-computing-device)

so, why my question was closed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jeff pointed out already communities get stricter, and because of the wide audience SU is especially strict.

Since this particular question was closed solely by the community and not by a diamond moderator, I am not convinced going against the community is a good idea.

As for listing older questions that have not been closed, understand that policies change and we do not always retroactively apply changes. Some questions where posted early on, and never made the home page again, and therefore remain open. When they are highlighted, like in this question, they suddenly generate interest again, and we start a new circle of closing wars.

Comment: Based on the answers already given, I for one wouldn't want to see it reopened

Comment: @Ivo that sounds a little bit harsh

Comment: @Diago thanks for the clear explanation

Comment: @system Why is that? He's just pointing out how he thinks about the question...

Comment: @systempuntoout: it's nothing personal, I just don't want such questions on the site.

Comment: @Ivo no problem at all, peace. For the record, I really love that kind of questions.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's .. mmm .. OK. Maybe "mostly harmless" is the right way to describe it?

This sort of thing would have definitely survived in the early days of SU but sites tend to get stricter over time in my experience.

I can support re-opening it, if it is edited to meet, say, 1 or 2 other SU community mods approval.

Comment: thanks for your support :).  I will definitely wait for the "Not Programming related" proposal for this kind of funny\grotesque topic.