# What happened to question "Worst Web Site Design Ever"?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I realise this question - https://superuser.com/questions/15798/worst-web-site-design-ever - isn't appropriate for Super User, but did it just get deleted and that's it?

IMHO it had some decent low class entertainment value and it would be a shame to see its answers disappear forever. Has it been moved or can it be moved to a more appropriate Stack Exchange site?

Answer (score 3):

**Yes**

It has been deleted and are visible only to 10K+ users.

**No**

It can't be moved since none of the other sites are out of beta and we don't know when moving to these sites will be possible. It will also depend on which site survive beta.

In short. If you want to see it again on a more appropriate SE site then feel free to re-post it.

As to why it was deleted, please see my answer [here](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1336/why-this-question-was-closed/1338#1338)

Comment: If it was a question of more value then I probably would repost it... Right now though I'll wait until SE matures further. Thanks!